# Building wheels for collected packages very slow and memory demanding. Can I skip it?

Tags: python, installation, pip, setup.py

I have this `setup.py` file for my project and I am running Anaconda3 with Python3.7:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from setuptools.command.install import install as InstallCommand


def parse_requirements(requirements):
    with open(requirements) as f:
        return [l.strip('\n') for l in f if l.strip('\n') and not l.startswith('#')]


class Install(InstallCommand):
    """ Customized setuptools install command which uses pip. """

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        from pip._internal import main as _main
        _main(['install', '.'])
        InstallCommand.run(self, *args, **kwargs)


setup(
    name="NGF",
    author="Ties van Rozendaal",
    author_email="git@tivaro.nl",
    maintainer="Thomas Evangelidis",
    maintainer_email="tevang3@gmail.com",
    description="\n*** An implementation of Convolutional Networks on Graphs for Learning Molecular Fingerprints in Keras 2.x. ***\n",
    long_description="Read the README.md file.",
    url="https://github.com/iwatobipen/keras-neural-graph-fingerprint",
    license="MIT.",
    version="1.0",
    platforms="Unix",
    dependency_links=[],
    cmdclass={
        'install': Install,
    },
    packages=find_packages(where='.', exclude=()),
    # package_dir={'':'dev'},
    install_requires=parse_requirements('requirements.txt')
)
```

The contents of `requirements.txt` file are:

```
pip==19.0.3
tensorflow==1.13.1
setuptools==40.8.0
Keras==2.2.4
numpy==1.16.2
```

When I do:

```
pip install <project dir>/
```

Python builds some huge wheels which take ages to finish and eventually consume all the memory! I don't know what exactly it does, perhaps it builds wheels for `tensorflow` and `Keras` which as massive packages in C++ with Python wrappers. All I want is `pip` to check if the required modules are installed, and if not, to install them, and then copy the python files of my project to `~/Anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/`. So simple! How can I do that?

Comment: Although you can skip building wheel for packages by using `--no-binary` option, this will not solve your issue because the packages you mentioned ship C extensions that need to be built to binary libs sooner or later in the package installation phase, so you will only delay that with skipping wheel build. The problem is rather that precompiled wheels are not available for your platform/arch/python version. Also, Anaconda is a somewhat different beast; try installing the dependencies with `conda` since they are most probably available precompiled.

Comment: I don't quite understand. First I tried `pip install keras-neural-graph-fingerprint/ --no-binary :all` but doesn't make any difference. Is it possible to install my package using `conda`? I couldn't find how.

Comment: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/recipes/build-without-recipe.html

Comment: As for `--no-binary`, you are using it wrong. `pip install pkgname --no-binary=:all:` is correct. However, as I already wrote, it will not "speed up" the installation.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are subclassing `Install` and overriding `run()` is inappropriate and will naturally trigger source builds. Don't do this; only the `install_requires` line is sufficient and setuptools will handle anything else.